# Should an array name and index be used for naming JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, naming

I was surprised that this works in JavaScript. My questions is, is this good practice?

```
var contact = [];
contact[0] = {};
contact[0].name = "Peter Parker";
console.log(contact[0].name);
```

Comment: Why does it surprise you? What makes you think is bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part? Setting `0` of `contact` is generally not good practice when the array is empty - instead, you should make an object, then `push` that object into the array.

On the other hand, if you're talking about setting a property of `contact[0]` - yep! That's the entire point of objects - you can think of them similarly to Python dictionaries, except you don't need to use bracket notation to access it.

You can also define the names right inside of the object:

```
var contact = {name: "Peter Parker"};
```

To push the object into an array called `contacts`:

```
contacts.push(contact);
```

Comment: `push` will set the `0` property under the hood. Not sure why you think doing it directly isn't good practice.

Comment: This is not true.  Performance-wise, using the index is much faster than calling .push() for each item.

Comment: Really, huh. That's funny, if it's really just an alias for `array[array.length] = ...`.

Comment: In that case would it be better to do something like `var betterPush = (a, x) => a[a.length] = x`?

Comment: We're talking about micro-optimizations at this point, but yes, you're adding the overhead of an additional function call every time you add an item.

If you're adding a couple items, it really doesn't matter.  If you're adding millions of items, you can start to see performance degradation when using .push().

Comment: If you know the current index, I'd recommend using a for-loop.  If you don't know the length of the current array, some would argue using .push() despite the small hit in performance is worth the benefit you gain in readability.

Comment: But even without a function call it looks like method 2 in this gist is slower.. https://gist.github.com/liam4/1e69797e4be7c0050da9

Comment: (In case one doesn't want to run the script, replacing the 1millions with 10millions and running makes method1 take 14768ms and method2 take 16132ms)

Comment: @towerofnix
"you should make an object, then push that object into the array." That would have been the way I would have done it, but this seems a very quick way, so I wondered about it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong is here, or surprise. You get equivalent of next code

```
var contact = [{
  'name': "Peter Parker"
}];
```

At first you create array, and then put object in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code provided nor is it good or bad practice; that completely depends on the context (use the right tool for the right job concept).

All you're doing is creating an array where the first item is an object.  You can nest arrays inside of arrays or objects inside of objects, or go even further and nest them multiple times.